# nunit3-console doesn't run any tests in my testlist file and no produces no errors

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I have base fixture and other fixtures inheriting from the base

1. Base fixture takes webdriver as a parameter to run tests on different browsers
2. Tests are all in class TestA and TestB
   I have created a testlist file with full testname
   namespace.classname.testmethod one per line ,

nunit3-console produces the following output:

```
Test Run Summary
    Overall result: Passed
   Tests run: 0, Passed: 0, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0
     Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Explicit: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2016-04-28 00:57:10Z
    End time: 2016-04-28 00:57:10Z
    Duration: 0.077 seconds

Results (nunit3) saved as TestResult.xml
```

Doesn't run any tests.

Not sure if i need to specify parameters in test name, if yes what is the syntax?

Here is sample of my code, I am using c# and nunit3:

```
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver),EnvEnum.TestServer)]
[TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver), EnvEnum.TestServer)]
public class BaseTestFixture<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
{
      //setup and teardown
}

public class TestA<TWebDriver> : BaseTestFixture<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
{
    //parameterised constructor
    //test methods
    [Test, Order(1)]        
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        //test steps
    }
}
```

TestList file has testnames as following:

```
namespace.TestA.TestMethod
```

Comment: Can you share an example of your fixture and tests?

Comment: added some sample code from my tests

Comment: Have you tried running with the explore option to determine what the test class is called by NUnit? It is generic and a TestFixture, so it will not be a plain TestA.

Comment: Thank you @Rob , it worked , i got the test names list by explore option and created a file with selected test names.
nunit3-console --explore test.dll > testnames.txt